# how many ways are there that 8 women and 8 men stands in a line in case that every man should just stay next to one man

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

how many ways are there that 8 women and 8 men stands in a line in case that every man should just stay next to **one man**

i mean if we placed 1st man in line we must place **another man** next to him and after that cause we have 2 man next to each other we should place a **woman** as the 3th person.
for example we can not have : M W M  or W M M M

*i tried to solve that but i could not.*

Comment: Try to take the total way of standing minus the way that no two men stand meet each other (like MWMWMWMWMWMWMW or WMWMWMWMWMWMWMWM)

Comment: @N.Quy: That is a different problem: it gives the number of ways that _at least one_ man stands next to another man.

Comment: @TonyK Oh, now I see. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Are men and women distinguishable or you just want to distribute 8 letters "M" and 8 letters "W"?

Answer (score 2):

First, pair up the men. This is equivalent to calculating the number of subsets of size $2$ of a set of $8$ elements, with the exception that order inside a subset matters. We get $\frac{8!}{4!}$ different ways.

Now, line up all the women. There are $9$ spaces available for the four pairs to go. Lining up the women
first ensures that no two pairs of men are adjacent. Also, take care of the order. The ways of doing this are ${9\choose 4} \times 8! \times 4!$.

Multiplying the two terms gives the answer:

$${9\choose 4} \times 8! \times 8! = 204838502400$$

Comment: Not only pair, for example, WMMMWMMMWMMWWWW.

Comment: @N.Quy That is invalid. Three men cannot stand together.

Comment: I got it. Missing the part $\textbf{next to one man}$.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that men and women are distinguishable.

First of all we should line up (separately) the men and women. This can be done in $(8!)^2$ ways. 
Now there are 5 gaps where we should place women, in such a way that at least one woman is in each of three middle gaps:
$$
WmmWmmWmmWmmW.
$$
This is equivalent to splitting the number $8$ in $5$ non-negative summands such that  the 2-nd, 3-rd and 4-th summand are at least $1$. This in turn is the number of ways to split the number $5$ in $5$ non-negative summands, which is
by [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)):
$$
\binom{5+5-1}5=\binom95.
$$
Hense for the number in question one obtains the answer:
$$
\binom95\times 8! \times 8!.
$$